# Google Keep Does not work after turning on 2-factor Authentication on Google Account

Tags: google-drive, security, multi-factor-auth, google-keep

I have been using "Google Keep" extensively to keep notes on my workstation, laptop and my mobile phone.

I turned on two factor authentication recently and Google Keep stopped working on my desktop and in the desktop browser. It does work on my Android phone (of course after updating the Google Account on phone).

On my Windows desktop I had it as a Chrome App. When I open the app now, I see a strip with a sign-in button, but clicking on the sign-in button does nothing.
[image]

When I try to go to https://drive.google.com/keep/ from my browser, I get the message that the "App is currently unreachable".
[image]

**Does anyone have a workaround, if this is a known issue? I can't give up two factor authentication nor can I live without "Google Keep"!**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but using the URL https://drive.google.com/keep/ is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the two factor authentication enabled, and I have removed and re-added the app from the play store. It's now working for me (Chrome app launcher, and `chrome://apps/` working), are you still having trouble?